# Query Still Pulling Records Even with Clear WHERE statement

Tags: soql, query

I'm really confused / lost on this one. Writing a Query to select Opportunities not of Stage '6 - Closed Won' and it still pulls these records. This is happening with no other picklist values in the StageName field, i am able to sucessfully filter those out if i so choose (the below is of course only filtering out 6 - Closed Won

Query

```
SELECT Id, StageName, Lead_Producer__c, Account.Overseeing_Advisor__c  FROM 
Opportunity WHERE StageName != '6 - Closed Won'
```

[image]

**Stage Name and API are the same**

[image]

Comment: Are you certain that all of those characters are hyphens and not en-dashes? I see at least one on your 2a stage that looks like an en or em dash.

Comment: Agree with David. It's incredibly easy to copy from a Microsoft Office product and get the "wrong" kind of dash.

Comment: I copy pasted from Salesforce to the Developer console

Comment: And all others picklist values work (when copy pasting), even 2a which does appear to have an elongated dash

Comment: Do you by any chance happen to have a space before/after the stage value?

Comment: Just checked both before and after and no spaces

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to differences in em-dashes or spaces. I have had similar issues with picklist value API names in the past.

Try modifying your SOQL query to:

```
SELECT Id, StageName, Lead_Producer__c, Account.Overseeing_Advisor__c  FROM 
Opportunity WHERE (NOT StageName LIKE '%Closed Won')
```

this should filter out the appropriate Opportunities